# Proposal: Merge iphone-sdk into iphone

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Currently there are a large number of iPhone tags:

Most of them have a very small number of questions and may be appropriate to keep individual, but there are 2 heavily used tags that are basically synonymous:

1. [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) (~5000 questions)
2. [iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) (~2000 questions)

Almost any question about `iphone-sdk` is about programming the `iPhone`. While the other direction may not be strictly true if you include jailbroken devices, looking at the 5,000 [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) questions and the 2000 [iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) questions less than 2% even mention the word jailbreak, much less are about jailbroken phones.

I propose that the [iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) tag be merged into the [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) tag.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to bump threads, but we really ought to do something about this.

As I see it, there are two types of development topics directly related to the iPhone: iphone-web and iphone-app.

There are currently the following tags that I *think* could be merged into iphone-app:

- rspec-iphone-sdk
- iphone-sdk
- iphone-sdk-3.0
- iphone-sdk-3.1
- iphone-sdk-2.2.1
- iphone-sdk-2
- iphone-sdk-documentation
- iphone-development
- iphone-developer-program
- iphone-app
- iphone-dev

And iphone-web:

- iphone-web
- iphone-web-app

And iphone:

- iphone-3gs
- iphone+post
- iphone-touch

I recently tried to make a post about an issue related to iPhone development on SO, and realized that there were more tags than I could possibly cover within the limit of 5.

Are there "best practices" for consolidating tags?  Could I just go do it, or would that be frowned upon?

Comment: Threads are made for bumping.

Answer (score 2):

### Tag Breakdown

- 5077 iphone
- 1930 iphone-sdk
- 124 iphone-sdk3.0
- 73 iphone-simulator
- 29 iphone-web
- 23 iphone+uiwebview ???
- 13 cocos2d-iphone
- 9 iphone-developer-program
- 8 iphone-os
- 7 iphone-3.0
- 6 iphone-application
- 5 iphone-3gs
- 4 iphone-web-app
- 2 iphone-privateapi
- 2 iphone-sdk-3.0
- 2 iphone-sdk-documentation

One each of:

- iphone+post
- iphone-2.2-firmware
- iphone-accessory
- iphonecoredatarecipes
- iphone-privateapis
- iphone-sdk-2.2.1
- iphone-sdk-3
- iphonevideo
- rbiphonetest
- rspec-iphone-sdk

You can't actually see any of the questions tagged `iphone+uiwebview` on the `iphone+uiwebview` tag page, unless they happen to also have both `iphone` and `uiwebview`.

Finding this out has lead me to ask [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7229/why-can-you-put-a-in-the-tags-field).

Comment: Fascinating, whether or not they are removed, I suspect quite a few tags should be changed from + to hyphens

Comment: Oh, and I am not proposing merging the subtags like iphone-sdk3.0 into iphone, clearly that adds additional information, unlike iphone-sdk. iphone-3.0 vs iphone-sdk3.0 is an interesting debate, but there are vanishingly few of those tags, it is not a huge change.

Comment: I actually do think that tags such as 3.0 should be merged in as well, now that that is what everybody is developing in.

Answer (score 1):

I see iPhone-sdk as a tag which should be a more specific pointer towards questions which are directly linked to the SDK portion of iPhone development. I don't see any reason to be merging them, honestly. I've always been a fan of the broad + specific tagging convention where questions would be tagged both iPhone (gathering a larger audience) and iPhone-sdk (telling that audience specifically where they are having a problem).

Comment: The concept of broad+specific is great, but as practical matter that is not how these tags are currently used. Over 90+%  (probably 99+%) of questions tagged iPhone are iPhone SDK related, and a significant number of iphone-sdk tagged questions are NOT tagged iphone, the effect is that we have one type of content spread over two tags

Answer (score 1):

These tags now has roughly twice as many questions as Louis first listed.

Personally, the fact that these tags are split is prohibiting me from getting a look at all of the new questions that are tagged iPhone-sdk. On pretty much every stack overflow visit I am looking at a page with a question tagged "iPhone." So I click that tag and see if there are any new questions to answer. If somebody tags their question iPhone-sdk then I'm going to miss it.

I could do advanced search options but... no. I'm not going to do that. It's not one click that fits into my regular workflow. I can't think of any good reasons why the tags shouldn't be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the tags already listed by others, there are also iPad, iPod-touch, and recently iOS respective apple-ios.

Some of the questions tagged ipad apply to iPad-specific features, but many apply to the iPhone as well (and are mostly tagged iPhone, too). Most of the questions tagged iPod-touch however, apply to the iPhone as well.

Maybe it should all be iOS.

Comment: FYI, `[apple-ios]` (to distinguish from `[cisco-ios]`) is the iOS tag.