# Why can you put a single + in the tags field?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

## I'm referring to tags which should be separate, or they have a '+', when they should have a '-'.

*Look at the follow-up answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7229/why-can-you-put-a-in-the-tags-field/7600#7600).*

Apperently there are several questions tagged with the tag `iphone+uiwebview`, and I'm not talking about questions tagged wtih `iphone` and `uiwebview`.

I noticed this when looking for a list of tags for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/proposal-merge-iphone-sdk-into-iphone/7228#7228).

I managed to find one by visiting the `iphone+uiwebview` tag page. Where I noticed that it did indeed have that tag.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883415/uiwebview-redirect-to-facebook-login-page), it has `iphone-sdk`, `objective-c` `iphone+uiwebview` `uiwebview` `javascript` tags. The only reason it shows up is because of having both `iphone`, and `uiwebview` tags, not because it has the composite tag.

[example-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990596/handling-zooming-and-panning-inside-uiwebview) has these tags `cocoa` `cocoa-touch` `uiwebview` `iphone+uiwebview`, but doesn't show up on `iphone+uiwebview` tag page.

Because you can add tags to the tag pages with a single '+', you shouldn't be able to add that tag to your question.

So please do something to prevent users from mistakenly adding any tag with a single '+' in the middle of the tag. That way special tags like `c++`, `gdi+`, `com+`, are left alone, as well as several tags with `c++` in the middle.

---

### Examples:

There are 22 questions tagged `iphone+uiwebview`, but the tag page show 60 questions that are tagged with both `iphone` and `uiwebview`. It doesn't, however show all of the 22 questions with the actual tag `iphone+uiwebview`.

There are 3 questions tagged `xml+flash+actionscript`, but go to the tag page, it shows 5. **None** of which have the composite `xml+flash+actionscript` tag.

There are 7 questions tagged `svn+ssh`. While there are 10 on the tag page. Only 2 of which have the `svn+ssh` composite tag.

Comment: If anybody can find another example, please leave a comment/answer.

Comment: How about COM+ and GDI+

Comment: @Brad: You're still missing things like c++cli or visual-c++-2005, both of which are valid tags. You're attempting to invalidate a valid character. Again, I'd support a warning if you use a new tag with a + in it, but I don't think it should be banned wholesale.

Comment: The main one I have a problem with is listed in the question now, I still can't view the tag pages for any of `iphone`, `uiwebview`, or `iphone+uiwebview`, and thats after clearing my cache.

Comment: Hrmm. I just went to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone%2buiwebview and got 60 questions back. Just `uiwebview` returns 80. What platform are you on?

Comment: Ok ... Duh I have `iphone` set as an ignored tag.

Comment: There are 22 tagged `iphone+uiwebview`, so the fact you're getting 60 shows there is in fact a bug.

Comment: 3 tagged `xml+flash+actionscript`, but go to the tag page, it shows 5.

Comment: 7 tagged `svn+ssh` 10 on tag page. 2 of the ones shown are tagged `svn`, `ssh`, `svn+ssh`

Comment: The only questions that show up in the `iphone+uiwebview` tag page also have both tags separately. As in the reason they show up, has nothing to do with having the `iphone-uiwebview` tag.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea. Aside from the fact that the C++ users will revolt en masse if you ban + from the tags, you also have 30+ tags that have a valid + in them, just on SO. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and type in "c+". Granted, there can be some tag merging to be had, but the point of the tagging system is that we never know what will come up.

Now, an automated box that will say, "Hey, you sure this is one word?" if the user creates a tag with a + in it is entirely viable and I completely support that. But banning it en masse is a bad idea.

Comment: +1, Valid enough to warrant an answer.

Comment: @Brad: Edited to address your attempt at an (albeit small) exceptions list.

Comment: The idea of a pop-up is enough to make me up-vote this. I suppose I don't actually know of any others that screw up the tag pages. Just `iphone+uiwebview`, because both tags exist seperately. This may not be a problem where only the one side of the "+" exists, but not the other.

Answer (score 3):

I've gone through and found all cases where there is a '+' in the tag name.

I've then gone through and marked all of them that have a **single** '+' in the middle, this is so it ignores the `*++*` tags.

- a+

  ```
      1  × a+
      1  × cocoa+checkbox+tableview # Problem
  ```
- b+
- c+

  ```
  10818  × c++
    796  × visual-c++
     78  × c++builder
     66  × c++0x
     58  × managed-c++
      8  × c++-faq
      7  × libstdc++
      7  × objective-c++
      4  × modern-c++
      3  × cc++
      3  × unresolved-externals-c++
      2  × dev-c++
      2  × lazy-c++
      2  × turboc++
      1  × aac+
      1  × c++1y                    # Problem
      1  × c++builder2009
      1  × c++-concepts
      1  × c++-standard
      1  × c++test
      1  × c-c++-mixup
      1  × cc++usersjournal
      1  × c-vs-c++
      1  × effective-c++
      1  × learning-c++
      1  × mac+setup                # Problem
      1  × open-c++
      1  × vc++.net
      1  × vc++2005
      1  × visual-c++-2008
      1  × visualc++2010
      1  × c++-cli
      1  × c++-standard-library
      1  × visual-c++-2008-express
  ```
- d+

  ```
     52  × notepad++
      1  × to-be-wikified+1         # Problem
  ```
- e+

  ```
     22  × iphone+uiwebview         # Problem
      1  × iphone+post              # Problem
  ```
- f+
- g+

  ```
    110  × g++
  ```
- h+

  ```
      3  × xml+flash+actionscript   # Problem
  ```
- i+

  ```
    187  × gdi+
  ```
- j+
- k+

  ```
      3  × gtk+
      2  × lapack++                 # Problem
  ```
- l+

  ```
      4  × mysql++
      3  × xml+flash+actionscript   # Problem
      1  × ssl+python+stomp         # Problem
      1  × tinyxml++
      1  × visual+studio            # Problem
  ```
- m+

  ```
     50  × com+
      1  × jvm+msil                 # Problem
  ```
- n+

  ```
      7  × svn+ssh                  # Problem
      2  × n+1
      1  × column+name              # Problem
      1  × ssl+python+stomp         # Problem
  ```
- o+

  ```
      2  × crypto++
  ```
- p+

  ```
      1  × php+javascript           # Problem
      1  × php+regex                # Problem
  ```
- q+
- r+
- s+

  ```
      1  × s+
  ```
- t+

  ```
      2  × project+                 # Problem
      1  × git+ssh                  # Problem
      1  × vb.net+sql               # Problem
  ```
- u+
- v+
- w+

  ```
      1  × formview+mode            # Problem
  ```
- x+

  ```
     14  × x++
      1  × ajax+hebrew              # Problem
      1  × checkbox+table           # Problem
      1  × cocoa+checkbox+tableview # Problem
  ```
- y+

  ```
      3  × spy++
  ```
- z+

  ```
      1  × blitz++
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the valid uses of the plus either contain a `++` or end in `+` the exception I see so far that might be valid and isn't just two tags like `php+javascript` is `n+1` which I am not sure what that's about.

Definitely trying to find things tagged `php+javascript` ends up finding things tagged both `php` and `javascript`, so that's weird-ish but explainable, probably even good behavior.

Comment: There is the possibility to tag your question as `php+javascript`, but it won't show up on the `php+javascript` tag page, unless you also have both `php` and `javascript` tags.