# How to deal with redundant composite tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Some existing tags are redundant because they are composed of two much better known tags.  They dilute filtering like spelling variants of simple tags do.

I mean tags like [python-multithreading](/questions/tagged/python-multithreading), where the tag has a meaning equivalent to a combination of other, much better known tags; and unlike [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) where the meaning is not simply composed from meanings of the parts.  There is also a [gray zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/is-tagging-a-question-excel-vba-preferable-to-tagging-it-excel-vba) where the equivalence of meaning (and consequently usefulness of the composite tag) is disputed by the community.

Composite tags of a particular syntactic form are discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7229/why-can-you-put-a-single-in-the-tags-field), the conclusion being that the plus sign is a legitimate character in tag names, and that the existence of composite tags is a site content problem to be addressed by the community.

**Should we use the tag synonym mechanism to replace a truly redundant composite tag with multiple tags?**

More specifically:

- Should one propose the composite tag as a synonym for **all** its constituent tags, assuming that some or all synonyms will eventually be approved, and be used as a collective replacement in the future?
- Or, should one choose just the **most specific, closest matching** replacement and propose the synonym only there?
- Should one just go ahead and retag all posts manually, where applicable?
- Is there any efficient way to address such tags outside of the synonym system?

Comment: Can a tag have multiple master tags?

Comment: That example tag has ~181 questions, most of them seem to be correctly tagged. Manual cleanup *could* be an option unless the Diamonds or Devs have a more elegant weapon for a more civilized age.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - When I search for a tag like multithreading, I expect to find any correctly tagged multithreading related question.  From that perspective, at least 108 out of those 181 questions are incorrectly tagged.  But my question is not about just one particular composite tag.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi - That's kind of part of my question.  I don't know.  But even if it can't, I expect the user to do the "right thing" when populating the tagline and end up with all the correct simple tags due to the synonym mechanism guiding them to one of the simple tags first.

Comment: I am looking at [tag:gnu-arm], which is like [tag:arm] and [tag:gcc] (or [tag:gnu]); thanks for asking this.